# Angular (6) динамическая локаль

Tags: angular2, locale

Как динамически поменять локаль всего приложения? (Получаю с Апи).
Не могу найти документацию.

Желательно стандартную i18n.
Для перевода использую - `ngx-translate`

Проблема с валютой + `ng-bootstrap`

Answer (score 1):

`TranslateService.prototype.use(lang: string)` используется для смены языка, заинжектите сервис и попробуйте `this.translateService.use(...ваш язык, например 'en' или 'ru')`

Comment: Смена языка работает. Проблема только с валютой. И переводом `ng-bootstrap`.

Хотелось использовать динамически локали с '/node_modules/@angular/common/locales'

Но как понимаю это не возможно...

Comment: @Mike, Если я правильно понимаю - Вы хотите, чтобы при смене языка менялась валюта, а именно число, соответствующее текущему курсу?

Comment: Не совсем. Не нужно ничего от языка.
При смене допустим магазина (он может быть в другой стране) я получу данные в новой валюте и валюту. Как настроить пайп валюты я знаю и работает.
Но также нужно настроить отображение валюты по правилах конкретного региона. Отступы, округление, символ отделения от дроби и от тысяч. Вся эта информация хранится в файлах - `/node_modules/@angular/common/locales`. Для старта могу использовать любую, но как динамически изменить в процессе работы - не знаю. Это и суть вопроса.